# Unable to transpile es6 to es5 using Babel

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I  am using babel to transpile my es6 code to es5 in node application.

I have used below babel node modules for this

"babel-cli": "6.24.0"

"babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.0"

"babel-preset-stage-2": "6.22.0"

And below is related configuration in package.json

```
 {
   "name": "twinconsole",
   "version": "1.1.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "dist/index.js",
   "scripts": {
       "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
       "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
       "build": "babel --out-dir dist src"
   },
   "author": "'test@test.com'>",
   "license": "MIT",
   "devDependencies": {
      "babel-cli": "6.24.0",
      "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.0",
      "babel-preset-stage-2": "6.22.0",
      "rimraf": "2.6.1"
  },
   "config": {
   "babel": {
       "presets": ["es2015" , "stage-2"]
    }
  }
}
```

I was expecting below es6 code which uses Arrow function

```
module.exports.print = msg => {
    console.log(msg);
}
```

to be transpiled to

```
module.exports.print = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
}
```

Instead the transpiled code still has arrow function.

Any idea what could be the issue.

Comment: I have  "build": "babel --out-dir dist src" in my package.json scripts , and I execute "npm run build"

Comment: updated question with package.json code

Comment: @baao ,  it's still the same..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Babel doesn't find your configuration because you didn't setup `package.json` correctly. From the [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/#use-via-package-json):

> You can alternatively choose to specify your .babelrc config from within package.json like so:
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "my-package",
>   "version": "1.0.0",
>   "babel": {
>     // my babel config here
>   }
> }
> ```

Note that `babel` is at the top level, not inside `config`.